# MethodAccessException is thrown in Release build created with MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have the following set of assemblies: Program.exe, Lib1.dll, Lib2.dll, SkiaSharp.dll running on .NET 4.5.

Program.Main calls Lib1.Method1, Lib1.Method1 calls Lib2.Method2, Lib2.Method2 calls Lib2.Method3, Lib2.Method3 calls SkiaSharp.Method. All methods are public, language used is C#.

When Lib2 is built in Release mode using Visual Studio 2017 everything works.
 When Lib2 is built in Release mode from command line using MSBuild the following exception is thrown at runtime: System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'Lib2.Method2' to access method 'Lib2.Method3' failed.

The MSBuild command line is simple:

```
MsBuild.exe Lib2.csproj /t:Rebuild /verbosity:quiet /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCPU;DefineConstants="TRACE;WIN";OutputPath=bin\Release\
```

How can I perform a build using MSBuild the same way Visual Studio does?

Comment: According to the construction of your solution, I have create a simple test sample, but could not reproduce this issue when I build the `Lib2.csproj` project with your command line from VS 2017 Developer Command Prompt :https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai1sp_yvodHfhEt-JEK-Y8-ntz8u. So I could not make sure that whether it is related to the MSBuild, the project itself. Could you reproduce this issue with a simple test sample? If yes, please share the test sample to us, so that we could reproduce this issue.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the problem with a simple solution created from scratch. It might be related to my particular solution/projects or code base. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: how about this issue now? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?